# .NET Remoting: Cannot connect to remote object in Windows Service except localhost?

Tags: .net, remoting

I created a Window Service and it runs fine in localhost. However, when I install it into a different machine (using my account), my client on the other machine returns "Unable to connect to the remote server". If the client runs on the same machine, it just works fine. I also tried hosting the same remote object in Console app, and it works from remote machine without problem.

This is the code in my service's OnStart():

```
   HttpChannel channel = new HttpChannel(8080);
    ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(channel, false);
    RemotingConfiguration.RegisterWellKnownServiceType(typeof(MyService), "MyService", WellKnownObjectMode.Singleton);
```

Here is the client code:

```
       ChannelServices.RegisterChannel(new HttpChannel(), false);
        MyService myService = (MyService)Activator.GetObject(typeof(MyService), "http://xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx:8080/MyService");
```

I found somebody asking this question before on Internet, but no answer. Anybody got clue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try disabling Windows Firewall (or any firewall, for that matter). It might be that the port you're trying to us is blocked.

**Important Update**

> And after you've determined that the
>   port you're using is being blocked,
>   re-enable the firewall and create an
>   exception that allows connections on
>   that port.

*(Thanks to Jim Mischel for his comment reminding us that this was necessary.)*

Comment: And after you've determined that the port you're using is being blocked, re-enable the firewall and create an exception that allows connections on that port.

Comment: Neil, you are right. It's the Windows Firewall which blocked it. However, I thought I'm using HttpChennel 8080 which is not blocked by firewall, right? How can I workaround this restriction? I don't want to ask all my clients to turn off the firewall just in order to use my windows service.

Comment: You say it's the firewall, but you say port 8080 isn't blocked - that doesn't make sense. Check the firewall settings for port 8080 to be sure, but if turning the firewall off fixes the problem, then you need to delve deeper into the firewall settings (don't forget outgoing firewalls on client machines) to get to the bottom of it.

Comment: Neil: I mean which chennel is WebBrowser using? That is not blocked.

Answer (score 0):

If you're working through Visual Studio and using its internal web server, it doesn't accept connections from external IP addresses. It only accepts localhost connections.